# C code does not work when int variable is updated inside loop

Tags: c, loops, variables

I am kind of new to C programmimg and haven't done anything in a while. I am trying to perform a simple numerical integration of a function.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
int main()
{

/*Constants----*/
double e0=8.85E-12;          //C^2/Nm^2
double e_charge=1.6E-19;     //C
double e_mass=1E-31;         //kg
double N=1E22;               //m^-3
double w0=1E10;              //rad/seg
double gam=5;
double f=(N*pow(e_charge,2))/(e_mass*e0);
/*--------------*/

double delta=50;
double step=0.1;
int array_size=2*delta/step;
double Re_X[array_size];
double Im_X[array_size];
double Re_X_KK[array_size];
double Im_X_KK[array_size];
double i,k;
int j,z;


for(i=w0-delta ; i<=w0+delta ; i=i+step ){
    Re_X[j]=f*(pow(w0,2)-pow(i,2))/(pow(pow(w0,2)-pow(i,2),2)+4*pow(i,2)*pow(gam,2));
    Im_X[j]=f*(2*i*gam)/(pow(pow(w0,2)-pow(i,2),2)+4*pow(i,2)*pow(gam,2)); 
    j++;
}

/*This is just a test*/
z=0;
for(j=0 ; j<=10 ; j++){
z++;
printf("%d\n",z);
}

return(0);
}
```

When I run this code nothing works, *z* does not get printed inside the loop, and the first loop doesn't run as well (I print the results to a .txt and get nothing).

If I comment the second loop the first works just fine. If I comment the first loop the second runs OK.
If I dont add one to *z* in every iteration, everything works.

I really don't understand what is going on, this happens only with integer variables. If I change *z* to a double, everything is fine (but I need it to be int).

Any help is really apreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: you should probably not be mixing floating and integer math.  Debug each line and print the values of all the variables to see what is happening

Comment: Define all `double` arrays as global variables or better - use `malloc()` like `double Re_X = malloc( array_size * sizeof (double) );`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I suggest you qualify all variables whose values you won't change to be `const`.

Comment: you never initialize `j`. It is random garbage, and its use as an array index leads to *undefined behaviour*

Comment: Thank you all! Will take your suggestions into account as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a debugger:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555808 in main () at demo.c:29
29      Im_X[j]=f*(2*i*gam)/(pow(pow(w0,2)-pow(i,2),2)+4*pow(i,2)*pow(gam,2)); 
(gdb)
```

You are using an uninititalized variable (`j`) in `Re_X[j] = ...;` and `Im_X[j] = ...;`

Comment: This was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This program has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since `j` is used uninitialized as a subscript to write into `Re_X` and `Im_X`, which then corrupts memory on the stack. This explains your observations how the program arbitrarily does or does not work when parts of the code are commented. The code being commented is unrelated, but by chance, memory corruption plays out differently between different runs of the program.

A helpful tool to troubleshoot these kinds of errors is [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), enabled in clang or gcc by compiling with -fsanitize=address, or if you are using Xcode, there is [an option for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early). Another great tool is [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).